# object doesn't support this action new x() after babel transform

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, amd, js-amd

I am currently converting a bunch of JavaScript modules to ECMAScript 6 classes.  We are using require.js for the AMD loader and were manually writing the define([], ...) logic.

We are using Babel to transpile the ES 6 classes back to ES 5 defined modules. My bablerc file looks like this:

```
{
"presets": ["es2015"],
"plugins": ["transform-es2015-modules-amd"]
}
```

A simple class looks like this

```
import x from "dev/x"
import ko from "knockout"
import z from "dev/z"

export class y extends x {
...
}
```

The output looks MOSTLY right:

```
define(["exports","dev/x", "knockout", "dev/z"], function(x, knockout, z){

Object.defineProperty(exports,"__esModule",{value: true});

// Bunch of generated crap
var y = exports.y = function(_x)...(_x2.default);
}
```

So when I try to do:

```
var foo = new y();
```

I get an "Object doesn't support this action" JavaScript exception.

I have tried to change the generated code (which I don't want to do) to read:

```
var y = exports = function(_x)...(_x2.default);
```

But that didn't do anything.  However when I change that line to this:

```
return function(_x)...(_x2.default);
```

or add this line:

```
var y = exports = function(_x)...(_x2.default);
return y;
```

Everything works like it should.  I do not want to have to modify the generated file every time we make a change, I just want babel to do it's thing and be right!  What am I missing here?

UPDATE: I am using system.js part of the Druandal libraries (durandaljs.com) that wraps the calls to require by passing a function called aquire a module ID and it loads it up.  So I do a call like this:

```
system.acquire(moduleNameAndPath).then(function acquiredModuleFunc(acquiredModule) {
    if (acquiredModule !== null || acquiredModule !== undefined){
        var item = new acquiredModule(); // Object doesn't support here...
    }
}
```

We are using this to introduce a pseudo polymorphic behavior when constructing view models that a view is bound to.

Comment: If you modify it as `var y = exports = ...` then you aren't exporting anything at all, just reassigning `exports`. Where exactly are you doing `var foo = new y();` it's not in your example module so it isn't clear.

Comment: Sorry yes, I am newing the object in a different module all together.  I am using require to ensure that the module is loaded (otherwise it wouldn't work at all).  I realize that I am not exporting anything with that first change, but that is just something I had seen on another search, so I just thought I would throw it in there as things I have tried.  This is about what the output of Babel is though...

Comment: What you are doing in the other module is probably the important part though. Babel's output is what I'd expect. You're outputting a named export named `y` that has a constructor in it. In the module where you're loading it, you'll either need to use Babel, or do `define(["y"], function(yModule){ new yModule.y(); })`

Comment: So the other module is currently ECMA 5 and I am just calling new y() (after the module is loaded).  I guess I had assumed that would still work but I didn't realize that this was happening.  I cannot convert everything to ECMA 6 and use Babel fast enough, I have to do it in chunks, so I was hoping this would work.  I just tried new y.y() (y.default() if when I do export default class and oddly enough that worked...  I cannot go and change all those spots though...

Comment: **Where** do you try to do `var foo = new y();`? Show us how you are importing the module.

Comment: Without a reproducible example of both parts of what you're doing, it is going to be hard for you to get a final answer. Please update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exporting the constructor under the name `y`. In your import (`acquire`) you seem to try using `new` on the module object itself. Instead, try

```
system.acquire(moduleNameAndPath).then(function(acquiredModule) {
    var Y = acquiredModule.y;
    var item = new Y();
});
```

Comment: This does work, however the amount of places I need to change and cannot change due to 3rd party controls makes this solution unavailable to me.  I agree though that this seems to be the accepted way to do it (factory pattern), and I will eventually get to that point, I have to move slowly so I don't break a bunch of other stuff.

Comment: I am accepting this as the answer as it is the correct way to do it.  The idea is that when you get to all ES6, none of this matters anymore, but I was not aware that we had kind of an unaccepted pattern.  I have spent the time to fix the code.  Thank you for the help!